# Average of integers not counting 0 as a number

Tags: java, math

I am trying to find the average of an array of numbers, whose value is taken from a `JTextfield`. My problem is that zero is counted in with the average. How is it possible to find the average but not include zero.

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{Integer.parseInt(math1.getText()),0 };

int sum =0;
if(numbers != 0){

    for(int i=0; i < numbers.length ; i++)
        sum = sum + numbers[i];

    //calculate average value
    int average = sum / numbers.length;

    totdata2.setText(Integer.toString(average));
}
```

Comment: 0's are important.. if someone gives you 0/10, you want to include that!

Comment: Use an "if" to make your code conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't count the numbers whose values are zero in the denominator when calculating the average:

```
int tally = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ){
    if (numbers[i] != 0 ){
        sum = sum + numbers[i];
        tally++;
    }
}
int average = sum / tally;
```

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the following syntax:

```
if(numbers != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int[] numbers // numbers is an array.
```

You **cannot do** `if(numbers != 0)`.

Inside the for loop you should check that the actual integer number is not zero.

```
int counter=0; // counts not zero elements
for(int i=0; i < numbers.length ; i++)

  if(numbers[i]!=0){
      sum = sum + numbers[i]; // numbers[i] is an int (a number)
      counter ++;

    }
```

**Second:** You should not do this: 
    `int average = sum / numbers.length;`

In the above code you are counting the zeros you are dividing for the arrays original length.

You should keep a counter of elements not zero and divide by that counter.
Check the updated code above.

It should be:

```
int average = sum / counter;
```

Comment: Of course, that's exactly the same as not having the `if` test.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it can't even compile... I don't know what he's talking about...

Comment: @Alboz thank you for your reply, however it finds the average if even one of the numbers is zero. for example 3+3+3+0 is giving the average as 2.25 instead of 3. My apologies I should not have left the if in

Comment: @Craig thats because of this: 
    int average = sum / numbers.length;

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work

```
int countOfZero = 0 ;
for(int i=0; i < numbers.length ; i++)
{
    sum = sum + numbers[i];
    if(numbers[i]==0)
    {
        countOfZero++;
    }
}
int average = sum / (numbers.length-countOfZero);
```

Comment: Please make sure before posting answers.